# Upload file styled button with preview feature in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-events

I have styled filed upload button and added preview image before upload... basically everything works as a charm in all browsers except IE...

Now to bring you my idea closer it looks like:
http://postimage.org/gallery/22cvzh2g/bcd61d61/

Is there a reason why image isn't showing in IE? I tried in IE9, but I just get the path, while the `$('#background-preview').removeClass('hidden');`  seems not to be working as it's not removing class hidden...

...also in IE and Opera as file path you will note `C:/fakepath/etc`... while in FireFox, Chrome and normal browsers it displays just file name. Any help is highly appreciated!

Now in header I have:

```
<script>
function clearFileInput() {
    var oldInput = document.getElementById("upload-bg");
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "file";
    newInput.id = oldInput.id;
    newInput.name = oldInput.name;
    newInput.onchange = oldInput.onchange;
    newInput.className = oldInput.className;
    newInput.style.cssText = oldInput.style.cssText;
    // copy any other relevant attributes

    oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, oldInput);
    $('#background-preview').addClass('hidden');

    var oldInput1 = document.getElementById("FileField");
    var newInput2 = document.createElement("input");
    newInput2.type = "text";
    newInput2.id = oldInput1.id;
    newInput2.className = oldInput1.className;
    newInput2.style.cssText = oldInput1.style.cssText;
    oldInput1.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput2, oldInput1);

}




function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#background-image')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(250)
                .height(170);
            $('#background-preview').removeClass('hidden');
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

In body section where actual button is:

```
<div id="FileUpload">
 <input id="upload-bg" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);getElementById('FileField').value = getElementById('upload-bg').value;" />
 <div id="BrowserVisible"><input type="text" id="FileField" /></div>
</div>
<div id="background-preview" class="hidden"><img id="background-image" src="#" alt="Bad Image File !" /><a href="#" id="clear-bg-upload" onclick="clearFileInput();"> </a></div>
```

And the CSS that takes care for the customizing file input is:

```
#FileUpload {
position:relative;
height: 50px;
}
#BrowserVisible {
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
background:url(images/button-browse.png) 100% 0px no-repeat;
height:42px;
width:290px;
}
#FileField {
border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
font-size: 13px;
height: 40px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 215px;
}
#upload-bg {
position:relative;
width:290px;
height:43px;
text-align: right;
-moz-opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
#clear-bg-upload {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background: url(images/icon-delete-input.png) top center no-repeat;
}
#background-preview {
border: solid 1px #ccc;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-icab-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#background-preview.hidden {
display: none;
}
#background-preview img {
margin: 0px auto;
display: block;
max-height: 140px;
max-width: 180px;
width: auto;
}
```

----------------------------- EDITED -------------------------------

Ok, I went to different approach via Ajax (using) upload and all is wonderful... I just can't figure how to send field value only. Right now it's sent like form, but is there a way to trigger send only the field. Right now it's warped in `#FileUploadForm`, but I want to use this within a form and since forms can't be nested... I am kind of stuck... except having two forms like I have now, but I would like that file upload filed to be sent like it is now, just without having to wrap it in it's own form.

This is script I am using:

```
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var fileToUploadValue = $('#fileToUpload').fieldValue();
    if (!fileToUploadValue[0]) {
        $('#result').html('Please select a file.');
        return false;
    }
    $("#loading").show();
    return true;
}

function showResponse(data, statusText) {
    $("#loading").hide();
    if (statusText == 'success') {
        var msg = data.error.replace("##", "<br />");
        if (data.img != '') {
            $('#result').removeClass('hiddenmessage');
            $('#result').html('<img src="uploads/thumbs/' + data.img + '" /><a href="delete-background-image.php" id="clear-bg-upload"> </a>');
            //          $('#message').html('<a href="delete-background-image.php" id="clear-bg-upload">Click here</a>'); 
            //          $('#FileUploadForm').html('');
        } else {
            $('#result').removeClass('hiddenmessage');
            $('#result').html(msg);
        }
    } else {
        $('#result').removeClass('hiddenmessage');
        $('#result').html('Unknown error!');
    }
}

function StartFileUpload() {
    $('#message').html('');
    $('#FileUploadForm').ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    return false;
}
$('#fileToUpload').live('change', function () {
    StartFileUpload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with paths — in HTML/JS, you can't get full path to attached file due to security concerns.  All you can get is file name.

Usually the best approach is to upload file to server with JavaScript when user selects file and then grab preview from that server.  You could provide some "delete" button which would enable users to remove pics they uploaded by mistake.

This would enforce deep changes in your application.  I recommend [File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) plugin.  Writing your own solution from scratch will be very painful because it requires many hacks for different browsers.

Comment: yes, I've used Ajax now, but kind of stuck with the issue (please see edited question) Thanks for help !

Comment: @Peter: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.  If you upload picture with AJAX, you need another ad hoc form created specially for this request.  You should craft upload response so it contains path to picture or ID of db record (I usually save picture with some GUID name).  You can include this ID in some hidden field of your "main" form then.  Also, you probably want to remove pics which were uploaded with AJAX but not attached to any gallery every few days.

Comment: No worries, it works same way as I showed in example... I am uploading it via php, so... all is ok and working as php takes care of file... it's properly displaying after upload on ALL browsers etc..., i was just curious if this can be submited without being wrapped within <form> </form> ... you know what i mean... like now it is onchange event - and it's auto submitting, but it's submitting AS A FORM element...